# What is data type and how is it implemented?

Tags: assembly, types, language-agnostic, low-level

I started programming 2 years ago and there's one question that bugs me at the back of my head all time when I program and I put to silence.

I understand the basics of microprocessor architecture and low level programming and I understand there is no such thing as a data type. It's just an abstraction to limit the way data is processed and control memory resources.

So I know this is a deep and somewhat unclear question but hopefully you'll understand the piece in the puzzle missing for me to make sense of the link between high level programming and what actually goes in the hardware.

So my question is : what exactly is a data type and how, where and when is it implemented?

Comment: Microprocessor architecture is about hardware. Types are about languages.

Answer (score 5):

A data type is an element of the semantics of a language. It is a set of rules about what kind of information can be represented by a variable in the language, and the transformations that apply to those types of information.

It is implemented in the compiler or interpretter of the language.   In a compiled language, it is implemented at compile time.  In an interpretted language it is implemented at run time - some of the rules being applied during the "initial parsing pass", and some being applied as the data itself is manipulated according to the semantics of the language during execution.

---

Elaboration in response to OP's comment:

A concrete example of what is going on might be the processing of this code, in C:

`int i = "foo";`

The C compiler first lexes this, and concludes it has a a keyword followed by an identifier, followed by an operator followed by a constant.   Syntactically, it determines that it is an initialisation statement.   It then comes to the semantic analysis and determines that it is being asked to assign a string constant to an integer variable.   At this point, it concludes that this is not allowed semantically **because an integer datatype is not allowed to have a string value**.   The C compiler issues an error statement to this effect, and **produces no output code, no assembly, no binary**.

The *effect* of the datatype was to cause compilation to cease.

The *implementation* of the datatype is in the C compiler itself - in the code/logic of the compiler.

You can't "see" datatypes in the "assembly code" of a program itself.   They exist in the mechanism that implements the language (compiler or interpretter), not in the resulting program.

Thus there is no such thing as "a piece of assembly code illustrating a datatype".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. that part I had grasp although it help clear things up. I have to excuse myself for not being clearer. I guess then what I am seeking for is a concrete explanation of what actually is going on. or a peice of assembly code as I have yet to put my hand on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well thinking about types in `C`

In [The History of the C Language](http://www.codingunit.com/the-history-of-the-c-language)  it says one of reasons Dennis Ritchie made `C` was becuase `B` (*the language much of UNIX was written in prior to `C`*) had really weak typing, so Dennis Ritchie "turned" the `B` language into the `C` language by adding types and structures.

*A drawback of the B language was that it did not know data-types. (Everything was expressed in machine words). Another functionality that the B language did not provide was the use of “structures”. The lag of these things formed the reason for Dennis M. Ritchie to develop the programming language C.*

I'll try and quickly cover this..

Looking at a typical x86 32bit register, `eax` for instance, you have;

```
00-00-00-f0h <- A bit-mask just to add some bits
```

expands to;

```
                                   ****  <-- [nybble] 4 bits
0000-0000 0000-0000 0000-0000 1111-0000b
                    ^^^^^^^^^             
                    ^ah       ^^^^^^^^^  <-- [byte] 8 bits
                              ^al
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- [word] 16 bits
                    ^ax
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- [dword] 32 bits
^eax
```

`dword word byte` are the sizes you can actually manipulate with instructions, these serve as (in a way) really basic types in assembly level programming, but these are just sizes, this isn't enough, we would like to have types to represent all kinds of things, not just sizes of data, for instance `characters`, how can we tell that a bit pattern is a `number` or a string of `characters`, better yet how can we tell if a `number` is `signed` or `unsigned`, you can't, a particular bit pattern only makes sense in whatever context you're using it in, this can lead to bugs, and confusing code, so higher level languages implement types to help make the data retain meaning and help to prevent hard to find bugs.

In `C`, say we have the string of characters of type `char` equal to "hello world", type `char *`, if we open this in a debugger and examine first some of the instructions and the memory, perhaps we can make some sense of this.

using `GDB` to examine the first 8 instructions in the `main` function we get;

```
(gdb) x/8i $eip
=> 0x4015d3 <main+3>:   and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x4015d6 <main+6>:   sub    esp,0x10
   0x4015d9 <main+9>:   call   0x401ff0 <__main>
   0x4015de <main+14>:  mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0xc],0x409064
   0x4015e6 <main+22>:  mov    eax,0x0
   0x4015eb <main+27>:  leave
   0x4015ec <main+28>:  ret
   0x4015ed <main+29>:  nop
```

take notice of this `mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0xc],0x409064`

What's this address (`0x409064`) being moved into to stack (`esp+0xc`)?

Well if we examine that address we get;

```
(gdb) x/s 0x409064
0x409064 <__register_frame_info+4231268>:       "hello world"
```

that's the address where our string starts in memory, so when we create a type `char *` in `C` we are really storing a pointer to the data onto the stack, then when we reference that type we just need to grab the address for it off of the stack, the good thing about addresses is we don't need more than 32 bits (`dword`) for each address on the stack, regardless of the types size.

I could assume that `C` does the same thing when we create a single i.e `char ch = 'a'`, lets check;

```
(gdb) x/8i $eip
=> 0x4015d3 <main+3>:   and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x4015d6 <main+6>:   sub    esp,0x10
   0x4015d9 <main+9>:   call   0x402000 <__main>
   0x4015de <main+14>:  mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0xc],0x409064
   0x4015e6 <main+22>:  mov    BYTE PTR [esp+0xb],0x61
   0x4015eb <main+27>:  mov    eax,0x0
   0x4015f0 <main+32>:  leave
   0x4015f1 <main+33>:  ret
```

**NO it doesn't store a pointer on the stack**

well that changes that, lets quickly examine the stack at a point after the variables have been pushed onto the stack;

note: gdb calls `words` what i called a `dword`, so when i ask for `5 hex words (5xw)` i mean `5 hex dwords` which is what i get.

```
(gdb) x/5xw $esp
0x28fea0:       0x00401f80      0x00000000      0x61000023      0x00409064
0x28feb0:       0x00000023
```

Look at the last two `dwords` on the first line `0x61000023 & 0x00409064`:

**0x00409064** is the address to our data `(char *)`

**0x61000023** this dword needs to loose a few bytes to make sense. ignoring `000024` we are left with `0x61` the ascii value for 'a'.

The compiler has stored the 'a' | 0x61 as the data itself right next to our string on the stack `esp+0xb = char` and `esp+0xc = (char *)`, as you can see (similar to assembly) types in `C` are closely related to sizes and a lot of the work is done by the compiler, if sizes of types are hard to determine `C` seems to use pointers (which are the size of a register), otherwise if it's a type whos size can be determined, the compiler just puts the data right on the stack.

*(by determine i mean control)*

And from all that i'v only examined `char`s!!!!

I'm sure their are lots and lots of other ways in `C` alone that types are implemented not thinking about all the other languages that exist and all the different ways they might do it.

Anyway I hope that helps you out some and i didn't mess anything up.

---

**Extra Info**:

Doing a quick search for `compiler design` [i found this pdf](http://www.diku.dk/~torbenm/Basics/basics_lulu2.pdf)

For information about any language, i feel i should refer you to its *standard*;
here is [C's standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)

Another quick way to find information about a language is;
do `google search` for `[x language's] documentation`

For information specifically about `types` i [found this paper](http://lucacardelli.name/Papers/OnUnderstanding.A4.pdf).

How i found the last paper is another good way to find information;
do a `wiki search` for whatever you're looking for and check at the bottom of the page for `further reading` and whatever references are on the page.

Now about the *assembly* code part;

You can and should use debuggers and examine how things work yourself.
This guide called [Beej's quick guide to GDB](http://beej.us/guide/bggdb/) looks like a pretty good start to `GDB`

**A quick way**: including the `-S` flag when you compile a `C` program in `gcc` will give you the actual *assembly code* listing for a program;

i.e `gcc -S file.c` will give you `file.s` filled with the assembly code, add the `-masm=intel` flag to change the syntax from AT&T's to Intel's.

Just remember the compiler doesn't try to write your programs so a human will understand them, so things will probably look a little crazy to you at first!

Comment: I think that this is an excellent description of the implementation of the *storage* of a datatype.   As you described, a string can be accessed by a pointer to the data on the stack (or elsewhere).   However, this does not encompass fully "what a data type is", nor "how it is implemented", but only how its value is stored in memory.   A datatype is fundamentally a set of semantics about how the value is allowed to be operated on by the language - even more so than "how its value is stored".   But ... your explanation of how it is stored may be exactly what the OP is looking for :)

Comment: You're right, i spent an awful lot of time on my interpretation of the "where" and only little on the actual "what" & "how", i think i took that direction because i read OP's comment to your answer where he said he would like a _concrete example_ and i just assumed he was looking for an assembly level discussion, also i think because you covered the semantics pretty thoroughly in your answer :)

Comment: @greenAsJade sorry, forgot to tag you in my last comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write such detailed explanations! That's very much what I was looking for. It all makes much more sense now :) If I do want to know more about, say, the way C implements data types, do you know of any good references that explain what happens at compile time and what code ( assembly) this results in?